# Directly access variable by parameter - make a generic function

Tags: angularjs, pug

I'm trying to achieve a kind of generic remaining function. I have a bunch of fields in my form, for example: **name** and **address**. These fields have a limit of characters size, my goal is to make a generic function to limit it's size when reached. So I made a sample function that works:

First on the page:

```
label(for='name') Name {{remaining()}} of {{totalChars}}
```

Second, the code to handle it:

```
$scope.totalChars = 10;

$scope.remaining = function() {
    var count = 0;

if ($scope.mName) {
    count = $scope.mName.length;

    if (count > $scope.totalChars) {
        $scope.mName = $scope.mName.trim().substr(0, $scope.mName.length - 1);
        count = $scope.mName.length;
    }
}

return count;

    //return calculateChars($scope.mName, $scope.totalChars);
};
```

When I type some input value into name field, angular stops typing when 10 chars are reached as well. But I've remade the function to turn it in a generic way and try to use it for any field I want to, but doesn't work as expected:

```
$scope.totalChars = 10;

$scope.remaining = function() {
    return calculateChars($scope.mName, $scope.totalChars);
};
```

...

```
function calculateChars(obj, size) {
    var count = 0;

    if (obj && obj !== 'undefined') {
        count = obj.length;

        if (count > size) {
            $scope.obj = obj.trim().substr(0, obj.length - 1);
            console.log('Result: ' + $scope.obj);
            count = obj.length;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

The `calculateChars` works partiality fine, the problem is `$scope.obj = obj.trim().substr(0, obj.length - 1);` because angularjs doesn't know what "obj" is and doesn't stop typing when 10 chars are reached, even counting the amount correctly.

I don't know how to make the first approach works for any case without duplicate any code for any text field I want to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Ito, do you have a jsFiddle or something similar showing the current implementation in its entirety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a directive. Here's an example of a directive named `remaining` that, given a model and a "max length" attribute, displays how many characters are remaining. It also prevents the user from typing more than the max number of characters; this can be removed by getting rid of the first branch of the `if (remaining < 0)` check in the link function.

```
app.directive('remaining', function() {
  return {
    template: "{{remaining}} of {{maxLen}}",
    scope: {
      maxLen: '@max',
      model: '=ngModel'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('model', function(val) {
        if (val == null || val == undefined) return;
        var maxLen = parseInt(scope.maxLen, 10);
        var remaining = maxLen - val.length;
        if (remaining < 0)
          scope.model = val.substr(0, maxLen);
        else
          scope.remaining = remaining;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/JanZm/. Note I'm using version 1.1.x of AngularJS to get access to the `ngTrim` directive, which tells Angular not to strip off whitespace in text fields.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, Brandon. I'm facing a basic problem. "MainController" is not found, popping up something like that: "Error: Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined". Should I named "ng-app" for "myApp" or how to register this module? P.S.: I've changed AngularJS version to the most recent one and my ng-controller is called by "MainController" as well. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure without being able to see your code. Make sure you're registering the controller using the [`module.controller` function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module).

Comment: Done! I checked this [link](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-directives-basics/) for basis of directive and I changed `scope.model = val.substr(0, 20);` to `scope.model = val.substr(0, scope.maxLen);` to capture max length. Thanks again, Brandon.